# Can the half-life of rubidium 87 be theoretically estimated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radiation, estimation, fermis-golden-rule

Can the Fermi golden rule be applied to give an approximation of this half-life?

Comment: I don't think so. Would you like to elaborate how you envisage doing it - you might get more detailed criticism of specific steps.

Comment: If the system is amenable to a perturbative treatment than yes in principle. In practice I suspect the problem is too hard.

Comment: Both answers are correct. Case closed.